# Using three state variable in Java

Tags: java, performance, types

Where can we use three state variable in Java? I mean `Boolean` (`null`, `true`, `false`). Can it be useful for performance?

Comment: You shouldn't, unless you want your code to end up on www.thedailywtf.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Readability and clearness is important. I would use an Enumeration with 3 values instead of associating a null Boolean to a state.

Comment: To boot, I imagine that checking for equality against an enum value is the same as checking against null. There is no reason to use null over defining a UNKNOWN enum state.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for performance, why not use a primitive `byte` (8 bits) and encode the states like:

```
byte b;
b == 0 // state 1
b < 0  // state 2
b > 0  // state 3
```

Comment: I imagine int would be better for performance. byte is good for memory.

Comment: I imagine less memory == faster comparisons.

Comment: I imagine there is no performance difference between any of the primitive integer (byte, short, int, long) types on modern hardware.

Comment: I imagine Java converts bytes to ints when doing a comparison: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.6.2 `"Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int."`

Answer (score 1):

With regard to performance, it's best to use the primitive. Anyway, it's important to know how the wrapper class is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Having coded in Perl a lot, I can see the usefulness of a three-states variable.. in fact, I landed here when coding in Java and decided to check, just in case, there is something in Java where I want to make only one call to trim a string and return something that tells me between three alternatives, which one the string starts with.

I think both approaches are quite good: 1) enumeration and 2) a 8 bits primitive approach.
Not in any particular order but today, I'll go with enum :-)